# Counting similar pairs

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

I was given a simple programming assignment:

> Your task is to quickly find the number of pairs of sentences that are
>   at the word-level edit distance at most 1. Two sentences S1 and S2
>   they are at edit distance 1 if S1 can be transformed to S2 by: adding,
>   removing or substituting a single word.

Since the text file was very large, I created a new text file with only the unique sentences and solved the solution on this file.

Now, say my program returns that $(s_1,s_2)$ are similir, and in the original file $s_i$ appear $l_i$ times.

What is the total number of similar pairs I had in the original file "induced" from the existence of $(s_1,s_2)$ ? is it just $l_1\cdot l_2 $ ?

There is also the need to add pairs that correspond to duplicates: If $s$ appeared $k$ times I add $${k \choose 2}=k(k-1)/2$$ (I ignore pairs with the same index,e.g if an element appeared once I add $1*(1-1)/2=0)$

Does that also seems right ?

Comment: I can't answer in the comment with a single world. But Yes, it is

Comment: @Exodd, I would suggest you post that as an Answer, changing only a single word in either sentence.

Comment: @Belgi: Don't forget to count the pairs of identical sentences since these also satisfy "edit distance at most 1."